# Passing parameters into a MySQL text file

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a MySQLCmds.txt file which contains some MySQL commands:

```
drop database DB1;
create database DB1 character set=utf8 collate=utf8_bin;

drop database DB2;
create database DB2 character set=utf8 collate=utf8_bin;
```

The way execute MySQLCmds.txt is

```
mysql -u$userName -hlocalhost < mysqlCmds_lyen.txt
```

I wish I could pass the DB-names as parameters into MySQLCmds.txt so that I can specify which DB to drop and which DB to create when executing the above mysql command.

Is this possible?

I couldn't find any way to do this at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

I mean modifying MySQLCmds.txt into something like this

```
drop database $DB1;
create database $DB1 character set=utf8 collate=utf8_bin;

drop database $DB2;
create database $DB2 character set=utf8 collate=utf8_bin;
```

where $DB1, and $DB2 are the parameters I pass into MySQLCmds.txt.

Comment: why not you are using your shell script file to pass these data base variabale names and making query there ?

Comment: I want to separate mysql command and shell script. I think this looks more structured and elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace it with *sed*

```
userName=root

sed  -e 's/DB1/DBONE/g' -e 's/DB2/DBTWO/g'  MySQLCmds.txt | mysql -u$userName -hlocalhost
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)